# Calculated column in Pandas Dataframe - calculating max of future values

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to add a new column to a Pandas Dataframe that calculates the maximum value of all of the following records in the dataset, i.e. the maximum of the current row + 1, to the end of the dataset.

The dataset looks like this:

| datetime | price | max_future_price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-02-25 10:00:00 | 10.00 |  |
| 2021-02-25 10:00:01 | 10.01 |  |
| 2021-02-25 10:00:02 | 10.00 |  |
| 2021-02-25 10:00:03 | 09.99 |  |

I am using a for loop and shift function (bad I know) but it was taking forever with larger datasets... is there a better / more scalable solution? I have spent a fair few hours searching and trying to trial and error my way through it with no luck. Thanks!

```py
for row in range(len(df)):
    max_future_price = df.price.iloc[row+1:].max()
    max_future_return = round(((max_future_price - df.price.iloc[row])/df.price.iloc[row]),4)
    df.max_future_price.iloc[row] = max_future_return
```

Answer (score 0):

You can revert your `price` column and use [`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html) to determine your `max_future_price`.

```
df['max_future_price'] = df.iloc[::-1, 'price'].cummax().values
df['max_future_return'] = df.max_future_price.subtract(df.price).divide(df.price)
```